# Do I have to Google Sign everytime to upload a Video to Youtbe using Java?

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-java-client

```java
public static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
    GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    int defaultPort = 5005;
    LocalServerReceiver customReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder()
        .setHost("localhost")
        .setPort(defaultPort)
        .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, customReceiver).authorize("userid");
    return credential;
}

public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
    return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
}
```

So Everything works for me but i need to login everytime which I would prefer not doing. Is it possible to modify the code or anything else so it does that automaticly with given Email and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client library will handle user token storage if its configured properly.

You forgot to configure `setDataStoreFactory`

```
// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
```

My TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH is just set to tokens then it stores them in the current directory.

```
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
```

Comment: Thanks soo much ^^
i think that works for me ^^